# how to facebook user authentic in AWSAmazon identity pool id

Tags: objective-c, aws-ios

```
-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
{
   AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc]initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1 identityPoolId:@"us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-ff6eaba0241e" identityProviderManager:pool];      

   NSString *token = FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData.accessToken;

   credentialsProvider.logins = @{ @(AWSCognitoLoginProviderKeyFacebook): token};
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: @Robert sir ,   i am try this code but Federated Identities console facebook login 0.0%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can authenticate the user from AWSAmazon user pool, not for federated pool.